# Do I understand たり here correctly?

Tags: meaning

> ＮＴＴドコモは、ドコモ口座を新しくつくることを１０日から止めています。そして、これからドコモ口座をつくるときは、顔の写真を送ってもらっ**たり**して、もっと安全に利用できるようにすることにしています。被害があった人に、とられたお金を払うことも銀行と相談しています。

Source:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012608551000/k10012608551000.html

Does it mean send a photo of your face or using some other kind of identification method (as the たり implies)  to try to help you to use it more safely?

Because I read from Maggie Sensei's site that:

> However you may hear/see a sentence with  just one たり ( = tari)
>
> 1. to do something and etc.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means "such as" as in "From now on we will take measures **such as** making you send an ID photo".